# Sweet Alert 2 script works incorrectly

Tags: javascript, json, model-view-controller, sweetalert2

When the json returns false or true from the controller, I send a message to the user with sweet alert 2 depending on the situation. But if my code enters the catch, I want to redirect an error page. But sweet alert 2 detects the value as false and produces a message, and I cannot see the error page.
What I tried; I tried if a json object is returned from the controller, sweet alert should work, otherwise it shouldn't work. But I couldn't see any error page.

Controler :

```
 public ActionResult Register(UsersRegister users)
        {
           ...............
            {
                try
                {
                   ...................
                        else
                        {
                            return Json(new { result = false, message = "Kayıt olurken bir sorun oluştu! Lütfen daha sonra tekrar deneyin." });
                        }
                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    return View("~/Views/Shared/Error.cshtml");
                }
            }
            ........................
        }
```

Js :

```
function registerSuccess(response) {
    if (response.result === true) {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Başarılı!',
            text: response.message,
            icon: 'success',
            showConfirmButton: false, 
            timer: 3000,
        });
        $(".register-inputs").val("");
    }
    if (response.result === false) {
        Swal.fire({
            title: 'Başarısız!',
            text: response.message,
            icon: 'error',
            confirmButtonText: 'Tamam',
        });
        hideOverlay();
    }
}
```